# CentOS 7 hangs after update on Workstation 10 after "[sda] Assume drive cache: write through" line

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, systemd

I recently updated my CentOS 7 VM and it won't pass the following line:

> [sda] Assume drive cache: write through

I tried changing the run level to 3 and run xfs_repair but it still doesn't boot. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That message indicates that the kernel was not able to identify the "caching" settings of your drive , but it should not block your boot.

Said that ... I would try to fix it , at least so that you can boot your vm again, on the Hypervisor side. What kind of Virtualization are you running?

Identify your drive in your VM configuration and see what kind of caching options you have for your disk (writeback, writethrough, none, ... ?) , change and restart your VM and see if it boots.